# Incorrect Sequelize query

Tags: jquery, mysql, sequelize.js

I have this sequelize query that doesn't return the expected columns.

```
db.conn.query(
                  " SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t2.name" +                   
                  "   FROM category t1 " +
                  "    LEFT OUTER JOIN parental t2 ON t1.id = t2.id "
```

This is sequelize log:

```
> Executing (default): SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t2.name   FROM category t1
> LEFT OUTER JOIN parental t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

And this is the result table:

```
┌─────────┬────┬──────┐
│ (index) │ id │ name │
├─────────┼────┼──────┤
│    0    │ 1  │ 'L'  │
│    1    │ 2  │ '10' │
│    2    │ 3  │ '12' │
```

Note that column `t2.name` isn't present in the result table.

However, I did this same query in mySql workbench I get the third column.

Does anyone have an idea about this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that sequelize uses a key map to load the result set back into the app. You'll need to provide **different** column names for all columns.

For example, you can change the first line to:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t2.name as name2
```

to receive all three columns as `id`, `name`, and `name2` respectively. The expression `as <alias>` assigns an alias to a column or computed expression in a SQL query.